# how to upload a file to selenium test running in docker

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Am running my selenium java tests in Docker's chrome container installed in my windows system.
Tests to upload will pass if i run tests in windows - chrome, but failing with error `path is not absolute: D:\xyz.csv` if i run same tests in docker.
Am pushing my tests on chrome node in docker.

Normal selenium tests work in docker, but upload doesn't.

Please suggest on how to copy this file inside container to give that path for upload tests..

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That is because Chrome would look for that path in the system where it. But the container is a linux based system and the file paths are not like this.

So you need to share volume while launching the chrome container

```
docker run -v localfolder:containerfolder
```

and in your test you need to use the contaienrfolder path and not the localfolder path

Comment: Thanks. Another way i got is commented below.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of this problem long time back.
Use below command to copy the files from windows/Linux system to Chrome container running in docker's say 'tmp' folder , this path can be later referenced in selenium tests running in Docker.

"docker cp D:\file.csv docker_chrome_1:/tmp/"

This above command can be run once Docker's Chrome container is up and running in Windows/Linux machine.

Comment: this is just a temporary fix